# Boost.Python: how to get super() methods called?

Tags: python, c++, multiple-inheritance, super, boost-python

I have a module with two C++ classes exposed which both have a method `foo()`:

```
struct MyClassA{
    void foo() { std::cout << "MyClassA::foo()" << std::endl; }
};

struct MyClassB{
    void foo() { std::cout << "MyClassB::foo()" << std::endl; }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(my_module){
    class_<MyClassA>("MyClassA", init<>()).def("foo", &MyClassA::foo);
    class_<MyClassB>("MyClassB", init<>()).def("foo", &MyClassB::foo);
}
```

In Python, I create a class that is derived from both classes:

```
from my_module import MyClassA, MyClassB

class Derived(MyClassA, MyClassB):
    def foo(self):
        super().foo()  # should be unnessessary - doesn't work anyway

a = MyClassA()
a.foo()  # works
b = MyClassB()
b.foo()  # works
d = Derived()
d.foo()  # only prints 'MyClassA::foo()'
```

Now I'd love to have `d.foo()` call `MyClassA.foo()` as well as `MyClassB.foo()`. But while `Derived.mro()` looks good:

```
[<class '__main__.Derived'>, <class 'my_module.MyClassA'>, <class 'my_module.MyClassB'>, <class 'Boost.Python.instance'>, <class 'object'>]
```

.. only `MyClassA.foo()` gets called.

How do I make the C++ methods call their `super()` methods? And does that work for `__init__()` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current approach (adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27134600/1668622) answer) needs some sort of wrapper which handles the `super()`-calls manually. The resulting classes don't need any special handling any more:

**C++ code:**

```
struct MyClassA{
    void foo() { std::cout << "MyClassA::foo()" << std::endl; }
};

struct MyClassB{
    void foo() { std::cout << "MyClassB::foo()" << std::endl; }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(my_module){
    class_<MyClassA>("MyClassACpp", init<>()).def("foo", &MyClassA::foo);
    class_<MyClassB>("MyClassBCpp", init<>()).def("foo", &MyClassB::foo);
}
```

**wrapper:**

```
from my_module import MyClassACpp, MyClassBCpp

def call_super(cls, instance, method, *args):
    mro = instance.__class__.mro()
    for next_class in mro[mro.index(cls) + 1:]:
        if not hasattr(next_class, method):
            continue
        if next_class.__module__ in {'Boost.Python', 'builtins'}:
            continue
        getattr(next_class, method)(instance, *args)
        if next_class.__module__ != 'my_module':
            break

class MyClassA(MyClassACpp):
    def __init__(self):
        call_super(MyClassA, self, '__init__')
        print('MyClassA.__init__()')

    def foo(self):
        call_super(MyClassA, self, 'foo')

class MyClassB(MyClassBCpp):
    def __init__(self):
        call_super(MyClassB, self, '__init__')
        print('MyClassB.__init__()')

    def foo(self):
        call_super(MyClassB, self, 'foo')
```

**usage:**

```
class Derived(MyClassA, MyClassB):
    def foo(self):
        super().foo()

d = Derived()
d.foo()
```

**output:**

```
MyClassA.__init__()
MyClassB.__init__()
MyClassA::foo()
MyClassB::foo()
```

Answer (score 2):

The C++ layer doesn't have direct access to the MRO information Python uses to automate superclass calls via `super`. If you polluted the C++ code with explicit knowledge of Python, you could directly create an object of `PySuper_Type` (must be called with two arguments; the magic that enables no-arg `super` would not be available) and use that, but mixing the Python code with the C++ code that heavily would get ugly.

In practice, the best advice with Boost.Python is probably [the same as for `pybind11`](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pybind11/master/pybind11.pdf#page=61) (a C++11 specific header-only tool that serves a similar purpose without depending on the whole Boost ecosystem), and the recommended approach there is to explicitly call the C++ level parent class methods, rather than doing so implicitly via `super`. There is simply no reasonable way to merge the C++ and Python approaches to multiple inheritance that doesn't lead to hopelessly polluting the non-Python code with Python specific code. `pybind11`'s approach would be:

```
class Derived(MyClassA, MyClassB):
    # Must define __init__ even though you only defer to parent classes,
    # or only MyClassA will be created
    def __init__(self):
        MyClassA.__init__(self)
        MyClassB.__init__(self)
    def foo(self):
        MyClassA.foo(self)
        MyClassB.foo(self)
```